# .net Maui DI Link label Text

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, data-binding, maui

I'm trying to pass a text obtained through binding from an existing base date to a new page to split items from another db3

firs file xaml

```
<Grid> 
    <Frame>                         
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>  
                           
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:ListViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

        </Fr<Label Text="{Binding ListName}" FontSize="Large" />                                               </Frame>                     
</Grid>
```

the ViewModel

```
 [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Tap()
        {
            string texto = ?

                 
                 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(Produtos)}?Text={texto}");
            
           
        }
```

the viewModel for the next page

```
[QueryProperty("Text", "Text")]
    public partial class ProductViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ListViewModel _vm;
        public ProductViewModel(ListViewModel vm)
        {
            _vm = vm;
           
        }
    }
```

i`m try to paste this information for new page but nothing i do works.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Shell, primitive data can be passed as string-based query parameters when performing URI-based programmatic navigation.

You can refer to the sample code below on how to transfer a string: `Texto` to the next page.

**SAMPLE CODE:**

**MainPage.xaml**

```
  <Button Text="Pass texto to next page" Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
    public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        string texto;

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Tap()
        {

            Texto = "This is a test";

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ProductPage)}?Texto={Texto}");
        }
    }
```

**ProductPage.xaml**

```
   <VerticalStackLayout> 
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding Texto}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class ProductPage : ContentPage 
{
      public ProductPage(ProductViewModel vm)
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext= vm;
      }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    }
}
```

**ProductViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MauiAppDI.ViewModel 
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Texto), nameof(Texto))]
    public partial class ProductViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        string texto;
    }
}
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions. We can work together to figure it out.